# Prettier run on CI warns about invalid file that does not exists

Tags: prettier

I have prettier that was working well but after I added file that didn't follow rules I got error in GitHub action which was correct. Then I added this file to `.prettierignore` and it didn't solve my problem.

I was trying to figure out why it was happening but now after I removed file that was causing problems I'm still getting error saying that it's badly formatted (simply impossible because file does not exists)

I'm running prettier with following command
`prettier . --ignore-path .gitignore "--check"`

I'm getting following error

```
[warn] public/mockServiceWorker.js
[warn] Code style issues found in the above file. Forgot to run Prettier?
ERROR: "format:check" exited with 1.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here is my workflow file

```
name: Validation

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Validation
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 16.15.0
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.15.0
      - run: npm ci
        env:
          MY_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET}}
      - run: npm run validate
```

Of course it does not occur locally

Answer (score 1):

Issue was caused by npm ci creating `public/mockServiceWorker.js` file and `.prettierignore` was ignored because I had custom ignore file provided with `--ignore-path .gitignore`